# Cosa vuol dire "scramazzare"?

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Siccome non porterebbe mai Lena a farsi una visita al Bellevue Hospital, l’ospedale gratuito della città, né farebbe mai entrare in casa sua le streghe del Comitato di prevenzione della tubercolosi, che gironzolano porta a porta facendo la statistica sull’incidenza della malattia nel distretto di Mulberry e se Lena aprisse la porta agli estranei la **scramazzerebbe** cosí duramente che per tre giorni non si alzerebbe dal letto, per un po’ Agnello non ha saputo se viveva con una tisica o con una gravida.

Non ho trovato il verbo "scramazzare" in nessun dizionario. Sapreste spiegarme cosa significa? Immagino si tratti di un vocabolo di origine dialettale.

Comment: Non ho trovato scramazzare ma sul dizionario [Napoletano-Italiano](https://it.glosbe.com/nap/it/scamazz%C3%A0) ho trovato scamazzà (scamazzare) che vuol dire schiacciare, ridurre in poltiglia, (pestare).

Comment: @abarisone: Anche in questo [*Vocabolario delle parole del dialetto napoletano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=QgtZAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA13-PA87&lpg=RA13-PA87) appare *scammazzo*, uccisione, calpestamento, e *scammazzà*, schiacciare.

Comment: Anche su [questo vocabolario](https://flore.unifi.it/retrieve/handle/2158/864495/28769/Antonio%2520Vinciguerra%2520-%2520Il%2520Vocabolario%2520del%2520dialetto%2520napolitano%2520di%2520Emmanuele%2520Rocco%2520-%2520Studio%2520ed%2520edizione%2520critica%2520della%2520parte%2520inedita%2520F-Z%2520-%2520Tesi%2520di%2520dottorato.pdf), alla pagina 924, si trova:

Comment: ***Scamazzare***, ***Scammazzare***. Schiacciare, Acciaccare, Pestare, Pigiare, ed anche Accoppare.

Comment: E appare anche [qui](https://books.google.es/books?id=aW4_DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=scamazzare&source=bl&ots=tLNI9roopI&sig=-viDc3NqqvfUEUUNxxXyM6sS6N8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIq-vssubfAhVaA2MBHYTaC0E4ChDoAQgzMAc#v=onepage&q=scamazzare&f=false): ***Scamazzà***, *scamazzare* = schiacciare, triturare, calpestare.

Comment: @abarisone: Ho trovato propio "scramazzà" (= pestare, schiacciare con i piedi, calpestare) in questo [glossario di dialetto minturnese](http://www.alfabetando.it/lettera%20s.html).  Infatti  questo personaggio, Agnello, proviene da Minturno.

Comment: Perfetto, potresti scrivere una risposta...

Comment: @abarisone: Cerco di farlo dopo.

Comment: E se avesse inteso dire "stramazzare"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Su questo [glossario di dialetto minturnese](http://www.alfabetando.it/lettera%20s.html) si trova ***scramazzà*** col significato di

> pestare, schiacciare con i piedi, calpestare

Infatti Agnello, uno dei personaggi che appare nel brano, proviene proprio da Minturno.

A quanto pare, si tratta di una variante del napoletano "scamazzà", "scammazzà", "scamazzare" o "scammazzare", verbo che si può trovare su parecchi vocabolari e altre opere sulla (o nella) lingua napoletana.

Per esempio, sulla pagina 924 di questo studio sul [*Vocabolario del dialetto napolitano* di Emmanuele Rocco](https://flore.unifi.it/retrieve/handle/2158/864495/28769/Antonio%2520Vinciguerra%2520-%2520Il%2520Vocabolario%2520del%2520dialetto%2520napolitano%2520di%2520Emmanuele%2520Rocco%2520-%2520Studio%2520ed%2520edizione%2520critica%2520della%2520parte%2520inedita%2520F-Z%2520-%2520Tesi%2520di%2520dottorato.pdf) si trova:

> ***Scamazzare***, ***Scammazzare***. Schiacciare, Acciaccare, Pestare, Pigiare, ed anche Accoppare. *Cerl. Fint. mil.* 5. Se l’ha chiavata sott’a li piede (*la tabacchiera*), e tuffete tuffete tuffete co li tacche l’ha scamazzata. *Perr. Agn. zeff.* 5. 98. L’arraggia e la sboria Co scamazzare li nemmice sfocano. *Ol. Nap. acc.* 4. 39. Da sta folla vuò esse scamazzata? *Bas. Pent.* 5. 4. *p.* 164. Scamazza sta tradetora. *Fas. Ger.* 11. 38. Che scammazzato chiù d’uno nce more. *E* 16. 4. No mare… da doje grosse armate scammazzato. (*Fig.*). *E* 20. 60. E la cavallaria passa e scammazza. *Stigl. En.* 6. 61. A te, gran dea Proserpena, scamazza Na vacca vecchia. *E* 190. Che d’Erimanto e Lerna scamazzaje Li duje mostre. 
>       Voce scamazzata è Voce chioccia. *Picc. Dial.* 1. 114. Dicette a boce scamazzata ec.
>         ***Scamazzo***, ***Scammazzo***. Schiacciamento,
>   Pigiamento, e per estensione Scempio, Macello, Carneficina. *Viol. vern.* 18. Nce vonno, pe nne fa scamazze, Vernacchie, trippe fracete e premmone. *Ol. Nap. acc.* 2. 60. Ma fu chi lo sarvaje da lo scamazzo. *Fas. Ger.* 7. 111. E sulo de nemmice fa scammazze. *E* 9. 96. Li nuoste nne facettero scammazze. *Cap.* Son. 204. Quanno facea de vierze no scammazzo. *Cort. Cerr.* 6. 29. Pe fa l’uno de l’autro gran scamazzo.

Anche in questo [*Vocabolario delle parole del dialetto napoletano*](https://books.google.es/books?id=QgtZAAAAcAAJ&pg=RA13-PA87&lpg=RA13-PA87) appare:

> Scamazzo, *uccisione*, *calpestamento* da scamazzà, e scammazzà, *schiacciare*, Fas. 
>         „Che scammazzato chiù d'uno nce more.

Sul libro [*La lingua napoletana. La storia. Le parole*](https://books.google.es/books?id=aW4_DgAAQBAJ&pg=PA176&lpg=PA176&dq=scamazzare&source=bl&ots=tLNI9roopI&sig=-viDc3NqqvfUEUUNxxXyM6sS6N8&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjIq-vssubfAhVaA2MBHYTaC0E4ChDoAQgzMAc#v=onepage&q=scamazzare&f=false), di Giuseppe Casillo, appare anche il verbo "scamazzà" o "scamazzare" col significato di

> pestare, schiacciare con i piedi, calpestare

e si discute sulla sua etimologia. E su questo [dizionario napoletano-italiano](https://it.glosbe.com/nap/it/scamazz%C3%A0) il vocabolo napoletano "scamazzà" viene tradotto come

> schiacciare, ridurre in poltiglia.

Answer (score -1):

L'etimologia è incerta tuttavia appare verosimile che il termine sia derivato per estensione dalla parola longobarda ***scramasax*** che indicava la tipica arma sassone a forma di *gladio* romano. La ***scramasax*** era dunque un corto giavellotto una via di mezzo tra un pugnale e una lancia. Ne esistevano due versioni: la *kursax* più corta e coincidente con l'attuale pugnale e la *langsax* coincidente con la lancia. Il termine ricorreva nelle battaglie e per estensione passare per la *scramasax* divenne *scamazzare* come sinonimo di uccidere o fare una carneficina. Interessante è il fatto che in numerose lingue germaniche *scram* o scran indicava il cibo mentre seax indicava il tagliare per cui è probabile che *scramasax* fosse all'origine un coltello da cucina.
In figura delle *scramasax* merovinge (credit: [Wikipedia](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scramasax)).

[image]

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!