# Significato di "scrafacciare"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, regional

Nel romanzo *Vita* di Melania G. Mazzucco ho letto:

> Di tutti i ragazzini del paese, Diamante era l’unico che non rideva mai. Era un sognatore. Agile come un gatto, si isolava sul ramo di un carrubo e da lassú, dove nessuno poteva raggiungerlo, con la fionda prendeva di mira i corvi nei campi. Non falliva mai il colpo. **Scrafacciava** rospi soffiandogli dentro l’aria con le canne fino a farli scoppiare. Andava a pescare le rane negli stagni del Garigliano e le ammazzava con un morso in testa. Acchiappava le anguille con le mani e non degnava di uno sguardo le ninne come Vita. Stava in disparte e faceva sempre di testa sua.

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe cosa significa "scrafacciare"? Non ho trovato questo verbo su nessun dizionario. Immagino sia un termine di origine dialettale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In questo [antico dizionario di Napoletano](https://books.google.it/books?id=vG4tAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA85&lpg=PA85&dq=scafacciare&source=bl&ots=39K7WYLQoi&sig=ACfU3U1Woi8G-35Z_ixyBekbFMVwbq9iKA&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijgqaG5fnfAhWR2aQKHT-qDpcQ6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=scafacciare&f=false) ho trovato  termine *scafacciare*, di cui viene dato il sinonimo scammazzare (scritto anche [scamazzare](https://it.glosbe.com/nap/it/scamazz%C3%A0)) che significa ridurre in poltiglia, schiacciare, calpestare.

Nel contesto da te citato significa che Diamante riduceva in poltiglia i rospi soffiandoci aria dentro e facendoli scoppiare.

Comment: Quindi il significato sarebbe simile a quello di questa domanda: https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/10180/cosa-vuol-dire-scramazzare.

Comment: Vedi http://www.alfabetando.it/lettera%20s.html. Sembra si tratti della variante minturnese di *scafacciare* o *scafaccià*.

Comment: @Charo esattamente è un sinonimo di scramazzare o scamazzare